# QGIS - Importing USGS DRGs

Tags: qgis

I have asked about this before.  If I import a USGS DRG raster for Anchorage, Alaska using EPSG:26706 - NAD27 / UTM zone 6N all the UTM coordinates are correct.  Now if I want to look at the coordinates in latitude/longitude and use ESPG:4267 NAD27 the image is rectified and stretched so the East/West looks twice as long as the North/South.  The latitude/longitude of the coordinate points are correct but the map just looks funny.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything wrong. Thaat's just how lat/long coordinates look in regions close to the north pole.